# I would like to deeply secure my port forwarding

Tags: windows

Here is what I would like to do.

1. use my smart phone to tell my server to allow a remote connection
2. allow a connection to occur say for minutes
3. stop allowing future connections after 5 minutes

I am not married to this approach and I am open to other versions deep secure solutions

Here is may ask....
Does anyone know of any open source software that will provide this level of support?

I am open to all brainstorming solutions.

Comment: A technology which could help you would be "port knocking".  You will require both a firewall/server for the Windows box (can't help you here) and a port knocking client for your smart phone - The android store has these.   That said, using a VPN like OpenVPN might be an easier and more secure solution.

Comment: What protocols?

Answer (score 0):

Cheap solution - download a hotkey program that automatically issues a script to rewrite the roter rules on the fly, then use the phone to rdp in and run the script when needed